# Data type not understood while creating a NumPy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a 2 * 3 numpy array as below:

```
x_sample= np.array([31000,28.69,7055.47],[79000,3.9,16933.26]);
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing brackets around the two lists.

```
x_sample= np.array([[31000,28.69,7055.47],[79000,3.9,16933.26]])
```

The way it was written the `dtype` argument was receiving the value `[79000,3.9,16933.26]`, which obviously cannot be interpreted as a valid NumPy data type and caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
np.vstack(([31000,28.69,7055.47],[79000,3.9,16933.26]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError: data type not understood` also occurs when trying to create a *structured* array, if the names defined in the `dtype` argument are not of type `str`.

Consider this minimal example:

```
numpy.array([], dtype=[(name, int)])
```

- fails in Python 2 if `type(name) is unicode`
- fails in Python 3 if `type(name) is bytes`
- succeeds in Python 2 and 3 if `type(name) is str`

(tested with Python 2.7 + numpy 1.14, and Python 3.6 + numpy 1.15)